# Como fornecer uma quantidade específica de strings a serem testadas?

Tags: python, string, algoritmo

Consigo testar se uma string fornecida pelo usuário é um palíndromo ou não (palavra ou frase que pode ser lida de trás pra frente ignorando espaços e letras maiúsculas e minúsculas como, por exemplo: Socorram me subi no onibus em Marrocos), utilizando o código:

```
string = raw_input()
stringSemEspacos = string.replace(' ', '')
stringTodaMinuscula = stringSemEspacos.lower()
stringInvertida = stringTodaMinuscula[::-1]
if stringInvertida == stringTodaMinuscula:
    print "SIM"
else:
    print "NAO
```

Preciso escrever um programa que, antes de receber as strings a serem testadas, receba primeiro um número inteiro, que corresponda a quantidade de strings que devem ser testadas. Se o usuário quiser testar 4 strings, o número 4 deve ser a primeira entrada no programa, seguido das 4 strings que serão testadas, e o programa deve julgar cada string e imprimir as 4 respostas, entre Sim e Não. Como fazer para o programa receber a quantidade de strings estabelecida, fazer o julgamento e só então ser encerrado?

Como estou fazendo:

```
i = 0
quantidade = int(raw_input())
while i < quantidade:
    i += 1
    string = raw_input()
    stringSemEspacos = string.replace(' ', '')
    stringTodaMinuscula = stringSemEspacos.lower()
    stringInvertida = stringTodaMinuscula[::-1]
    if stringInvertida == stringTodaMinuscula:
        print "SIM"
    else:
        print "NAO"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode solicitar que o usuário informe a quantidade de palavras a serem lidas, para isso, pode usar a variável `quantidade` que vai guardar a quantidade de palavras, e em seguida definir uma variável `i` que será incrementada em um loop `while` e verificar se `i` é menor que `quantidade`, e dentro do loop fazer a leitura.

Veja um exemplo:

```
i = 0
quantidade = input("Quaintidade de palavras a seram lidas: ")

while (i < quantidade):
    palavra = raw_input("Palavra: ")
    print (palavra)
    i += 1
```

Entrada:

> 3

Entrada:

> Palavra1

Saída:

> Palavra1

Entrada:

> Palavra2

Saída:

> Palavra2

Entrada:

> Palavra3

Saída:

> Palavra3

Veja a adaptação para solucionar o problema de verificação de palavras.

Código:

```
def ehPalindromo(palavra):
    stringSemEspacos = palavra.replace(' ', '')
    stringTodaMinuscula = stringSemEspacos.lower()
    stringInvertida = stringTodaMinuscula[::-1]

    if stringInvertida == stringTodaMinuscula: return "SIM"
    else: return "NAO"

i = 0
palavras = []
quantidade = input("Quaintidade de palavras a seram lidas: ")

while (i < quantidade):
    palavras.append(raw_input("Palavra: "))
    i += 1

for p in palavras:
    print("A palavra {} eh Palindromo: {}".format(p, ehPalindromo(p)))
```

Entrada:

> 2

Entrada:

> ovo

Entrada:

> ave

Saída:

> A palavra ovo eh Palindromo: SIM
>   A palavra ave eh Palindromo: NAO

Primeiro eu definir uma lista `palavras` que vai guardar as palavras informadas pelo usuário de acordo com a quantidade especificada no inicio do programa, em seguida obtive a quantidade de palavras que deve ser informada e guardei na variável `quantidade`, e fiz a leitura das palavras e guardei na lista `palavras` e por fim fiz a exibição de todas palavras digitadas e validadas através do método `ehPalindromo()` que retorna `SIM` ou `NAO`.

Comment: Funciona, mas o resultado do julgamento deve ser impresso apenas no final, ou seja, após todas as strings serem fornecidas. Como proceder?

Comment: @GuilhermeSantanaDeSouza editei a resposta.

Comment: Obrigado, farei as mudanças.

Comment: Notei que usou a função append(). Eu ainda não a estudei, mas farei uma lida para entender. Muito obrigado!